# Can schema be upgraded to Exchange 2010 SP2 before installing Exchange SP1?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

It seems there's no `Exchange 2010 with SP2` integrated available on MSDN so I thought I would just download `Exchange 2010 with SP1` and do schema in `Active Directory` and then before even installing Exchange I would update it again to `SP2`. I think this should work but maybe someone already done it before and knows if there's any issues that may come up because of this? Or should I go the long way and expand schema to `SP1`, install `Exchange` on 4 servers and then do the expanding to `SP2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Package:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28190
This is the *full* package (integrated SP2), as per the "Additional Info":

> This Exchange Server 2010 SP2 software may be used to perform a **new
>   installation** or to update an existing Exchange Server 2010
>   installation to Service Pack 2 (SP2) level.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2010 service packs are actually full installers, you can download Exchange 2010 SP2 and install it on new servers; the ISO images on MSDN are there only for convenience, but are functionally equivalent to the standard service pack download.

Just download Exchange 2010 SP2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28190) and run the installer from it; it will be much more quick and clean than installing SP1 and then updating to SP2.

Comment: You're saying that 4.6gb .iso is equivalent to 500mb sp2? :-)

Comment: Yes, it is, minus the UM language packs which are packaged in the ISO images but not in the SP download. They can be downloaded separately, if you need them.

Comment: You learn something new every day. I will accept Michel answer at it seems his was first.